# Hive alter location statement not working

Tags: hive

```
hive> alter table my_table_name set location "hdfs://nameservice1/foo";
OK
Time taken: 0.173 seconds
hive> alter table my_table_name set location "hdfs://nameservice1/foo/bar";
Authorization failed:org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: action WRITE not permitted on path hdfs://nameservice1/foo for user hadoop_user. Use show grant to get more details.
```

As seen in the above screen output, the alter table location is working exactly once on the external table and subsequently it is throwing an error. 
Please advice how I could get the alter table location statement to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out the error and fixed it. 
The issue was that during the creation of the table i set its location to a non existent path on hdfs. So when i was trying to alter its location,it wasn't allowing me to do so.

The resolution:
I first created the directory to which the table was currently pointed to and then created the directory to which i wanted to point the table to. Then the alter table location statement worked as required.

Answer (score 1):

On hive terminal run below command

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> SET LOCATION "hdfs://file_path_in_HDFS";
```

HDFS: is value against fs.defaultFS property in core-site.xml
You can also use `S3`, make sure the location is quoted (`"` or `'`)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best is to use a script to check that using

```
hdfs fs -ls ///
```

and then to call `beeline` with an external script