# hive: external partitioned table without location

Tags: hadoop, hive

Is it possible to create external partitioned table without location? I want to add all the locations later, together with partitions.

i tried:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS a.b
(line STRING)
COMMENT 'abc'
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
PARTITIONED BY day;
```

but i got `ParseException`: `missing EOF at 'PARTITIONED' near 'TEXTFILE'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so, as said in [alter location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21321146/hive-alter-location-statement-not-working).
But anyway, i think your query as some errors and the correct script would be :

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS a.b
 (line STRING)
 COMMENT 'abc'
 PARTITIONED BY (day String)
 ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\n'
 STORED AS TEXTFILE
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you have not specified data type for your partition column "day". And you can create a HIVE external table without location and can use ALTER table options later to change the location.