# Hive external table with empty location

Tags: hive, hortonworks-data-platform

I have a hive table for which the location is *`hdfs://:8020/specific/path`*
As you can see, there is no host, meaning that ANY query **(SELECT, ALTER TABLE SET LOCATION, SHOW)** will fail with the error:

> org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while compiling
>   statement: FAILED: SemanticException Unable to fetch table bounce.
>   java.io.IOException: Incomplete HDFS URI, no host:
>   hdfs://:8020/specific/path

As I cannot alter the location of this table via Hive itself, is there a workaround?

My idea was to hit the metastore (mysql) directly, but except for the DBS table which holds a location field (irrelevant apparently, as the path is something completely different, whereas the host is OK) I cannot find anything.

On a side not, the empty host is due to me (wrongly, obiously) running an ALTER statement with an empty host. Hive accepted it happily unfortunately.

If it matters this is the latest HDP 2.5 with Hive 1.2.1.2.5.

Comment: See [work around here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21321146/hive-alter-location-statement-not-working).  It's kind of a hack, but it should work.

Comment: @Andrew thanks but I already tried without success. The issue is not that the path does not exist, but that the hostname is empty. I thus cannot create a temporary directory on a non-existing server.